# Add scala capabilities into an existing EJB eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, ide, ejb-3.1

I have an existing EJB project set up in Eclipse Helios, and would like to slowly introduce Scala into the project. The Scala IDE has been installed successfully, and I'm able to create standalone scala project.  The issue however comes when trying to use my existing project with scala additions.  I've went as far as manually editing the .project, .classpath, and related files under .settings of the project's home directory for eclipse.

However I still have the issue where the Java compiler tries to compiles .scala classes, which results in errors and ultimately not being able to build the project.

Has anyone faced a similar scenario or are there any workarounds?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to right-click the project, go to "Scala" and click on "add scala nature". Then `.scala` files should be recognized as such. You might also have to add the scala library to your dependencies. Depending on whether this is a "simple" Eclipse project or you're using Maven there might be other steps required.

Comment: Thanks for your help Kim. I ended up recreating the projects as Scala projects, then adding EJB capabilities to them. Even with the scala-ide plugin installed, I couldn't find the add scala capabilities in the context menu. Scala tooling seems to a ways off before being mature.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on project, and choose **Configure**/Add Scala Nature.