# Scala project as "sub-project" of Java project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, scala

I'm writing a Scala "plugin" to a Java project. (Essentially I'm writing a Scala class that is a subclass of a Java class. It is intended to run in the Java application.) I can create both the Java project and the Scala project in the Scala/eclipse IDE, and I can tell one of them to refer to the other. But when I try to tell each to refer to the other I get an error message saying that I have a cycle in my build path. When I leave out the reference from the Java project to the Scala project (but include the reference from the Scala project to the Java project) I'm able to write the subclass and refer to the required Java classes. But now the Java application can't see the Scala subclass. Is there a good way to accomplish something like this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible in general to create cyclic references between projects. And it is quite natural. Suppose you have projects 'A' and 'B' which are interdependent. This means that in order to compile 'B' you should have 'A' already compiled. But to compile 'A' you need 'B' to be compiled. How do you break such loop?

That said, in some *particular* cases it *may* be possible. For example, if there are no dependency cycles between *classes* in these projects, i.e. there are no dependency loops like `com.a.X -> com.b.Y -> com.b.Z -> com.a.X`, then it may be possible to compile both projects in chunks until both of them are fully compiled. But this would require sophisticated algorithms and dependency tracking system which is just not worth it.

Plugin-based systems usually are structured in the following way. Main project is separated in two: actual program and its plugin API (actual program depends on this API). Then there are plugins which depend on the API but not on the main program. The main program now can have dependencies on plugins, because there are no loops now.

```
+------------------------+
|                        |
+-> Plugin 1 --+      Project
|              |         |
+-> Plugin 2 --+--+      V
|              |  +-->  API
+-> Plugin 3 --+
```

Even better is to link the program with plugins at runtime. Then there are no compile-time dependencies of `Project` on plugins at all. Runtime system (e.g. OSGi or JBoss Modules or something custom) becomes responsible for finding and loading plugins at runtime. This approach will require some changes in the build system and in the way you launch your project, but it may be worth it. This depends on your actual requirements, of course.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402269/add-scala-capabilities-into-an-existing-ejb-eclipse-project?rq=1) StackOverflow question seems to solve my problem. Its solution is to "Add Scala Nature" to the Java project: right click the project and select Configure > Add Scala Nature.  After doing that it's possible to include Scala files within a Java project! That's it.

Comment: This just makes your project a Scala project, and Scala projects can include Java files.